# converse of theorema egregium

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a $3$ dimensional Riemannian manifold and $N$ is any surface imbedded in $M$. If the theorema egregium holds for $N$ does it follow that $M$ is flat? The way I'm thinking of the theorema is that everywhere on $N$, the scalar curvature equals twice the Gaussian curvature $$S=2K.$$

Comment: I don't really understand. The theorema egregium to me is that the curvature of a surface is entirely determined by the metric on the surface, rather than any embedding into some other space. That is to say, the notion of Gaussian curvature depends only on the metric of a surface. This statement does not actually depend on an embedding into a 3-manifold $M$, and is true for every surface whatsoever.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I guess OP means the following: For each surface in M we have its 2nd fundamental form II(x), which is an extrinsic invariant. Now take product of the eigenvalues of II(x). Suppose that the resulting quantity is an intrinsic invariant for all surfaces in M. What does it say about the curvature of M?

Comment: yes @MikeMiller that is what I mean. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question remains confusingly stated. I agree with @studiosus that the intent of the question is to ask this: If the *intrinsic* Gaussian curvature of $N$ is equal to the *extrinsic* Gaussian curvature of $N$ (at every point), then must the ambient manifold be flat, i.e., a Riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature $0$? The answer is that this suffices.

This follows immediately from the Gauss equations for a submanifold (which you can find in Kobayashi-Nomizu, Spivak, doCarmo, etc.). Basically they say that the sectional curvature of $N$ is the sum of the determinant of the second fundamental form and the sectional curvature of $M$ for the tangent $2$-plane of $N$. If $M$ is flat, we're obviously done. But need it be? No. For example, let $M = \Sigma\times\Bbb R$ for any Riemannian surface $\Sigma$, and let $N = \Gamma\times\Bbb R\subset M$ for any curve $\Gamma\subset\Sigma$. The cylinder $N$ is intrinsically flat, its extrinsic Gaussian curvature is also $0$, but $M$ is clearly not flat (e.g., take $\Sigma$ to be the usual $S^2$).

If we know that the result holds for arbitrary surfaces $N$, then, of course, $M$ must be flat, as the sectional curvatures of arbitrary $2$-planes must then all be $0$.